# How to write color Unicode emoji in the IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, unicode, emoji

I want to write colored Unicode emoji in IE.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>


<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

If I run the code above on chrome and edge, it comes out as a colored cat face emoticon.

But in IE, the emoticons come out all monochrome as below picture.
[image]

How to use color Unicode emoji in the IE browser?

I'm very sorry for the basic question.
But I didn't know which keyword to search for it.
Thank you for reading the questions and I hope you have a good day.

Comment: IE is dead, please leave him alone.

Comment: @SMAKSS I really really really want to leave him... But.. for others who still use IE, I need to solve this problem... ㅠㅠ

Comment: @mplungjan I want to display emoticons like that site!! It also displays colorful emoticons in IE, But I don't know how to..!

Comment: @J4BEZ Yeah, sorry, I found the set of font-family strings you need on the site with all the emojis.
`apple color emoji,segoe ui emoji,noto color emoji,android emoji,emojisymbols,emojione mozilla,twemoji mozilla,segoe ui symbol`

Comment: I really appreciate both @mplungjan and SMAKSS. Thanks for your reply, I I can finally solve this problem.ᅲᅲᅲ    I dream of a day when all users are independent of IE.

Comment: Thank you for all!!! I wish all you have a nice day and good health!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, **I strongly suggest leaving IE alone, since there is no propper [support](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/windows/end-of-ie-support) on it anymore**. But if you insist on doing this on IE, Microsoft provided a way to deal with this issue. It may seem tricky but AFAIK, it is the only way to make the emojis work as expected. **So apparently, Microsoft polished emoji live in a specific system font named `Segoe UI Emoji`**. In order to use it, you just have to define a class or something and then assign it to your specific elements with emojis.

So Your final code should be something like this:

```css
.emoji {
  font-family: "Segoe UI Emoji";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>


<body>
  <span class="emoji"></span>
</body>

</html>
```

**NOTE:** As @mplungjan told us in comments if you want to be more precise with cross browsing functionality you can use below one instead:

```css
.emoji {
  font-family: apple color emoji, segoe ui emoji, noto color emoji, android emoji, emojisymbols, emojione mozilla, twemoji mozilla, segoe ui symbol;
}
```

Comment: `font-family:apple color emoji,segoe ui emoji,noto color emoji,android emoji,emojisymbols,emojione mozilla,twemoji mozilla,segoe ui symbol`

Comment: I really hate IE and I already use the Chrome browser.

But there are still many people using IE in Korea, so I have to cross-browsing for more users to use the site without discomfort. I want to cry.